# How can I delete events or even event series when they are cancelled using google calendar api for python?

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

I created a python program/script to help me update many calendars at once from a google sheets document. It runs pretty neatly.

I also created a function that would iterate over all calendars of interest and delete the event series and events alike. This function seems to only work on some calendars and not all. When I check my online google calendars some still have the events and event series not deleted. When I print out the event series json it shows that the status is 'cancelled' and I cannot do anything about it except go to each calendar it failed on and delete the events series myself manually.

any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!!!

I've just recently started with this whole google api thing so I might be missing something in my code somehow.

```py
def Delete_Events():
    calendars=googleServices['Calendar'].calendarList().list().execute()
    for calendar in calendars['items']:
        if 'IAT' in calendar['summary'] or 'Possible' in calendar['summary']:
            print(calendar['summary'])
            gevents = googleServices['Calendar'].events().list(calendarId=calendar['id']).execute()
            for gevent in gevents['items']:
                try:
                    googleServices['Calendar'].events().delete(calendarId=calendar['id'], eventId=gevent['id']).execute()
                    time.sleep(2)
                    pass
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)

                instances = googleServices['Calendar'].events().instances(calendarId=calendar['id'],eventId=gevent['id']).execute()
                for instance in instances['items']:

                    print(instance['summary'])

                    try:


                        googleServices['Calendar'].events().delete(calendarId=calendar['id'], eventId=instance['recurringEventId']).execute()
                        time.sleep(2)
                        break

                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                        break
```

And here is the json I print out for the events

```
{'kind': 'calendar#event', 'etag': '"3222549224124000"', 'id': 'm80coonp168fml4hec4tq777cc_20210101T130000Z', 'status': 'cancelled', 'recurringEventId': 'm80coonp168fml4hec4tq777cc', 'originalStartTime': {'dateTime': '2021-01-01T07:00:00-06:00', 'timeZone': 'America/Mexico_City'}}
```

And here is the instance json I am able to print out

```
<HttpError 410 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/la2gtl3ih4r7o14aj7edhe1luc%40group.calendar.google.com/events/m80coonp168fml4hec4tq777cc_20210101T130000Z? returned "Resource has been deleted">

{'kind': 'calendar#event', 'etag': '"3222549224908000"', 'id': 'm80coonp168fml4hec4tq777cc_20210104T130000Z', 'status': 'cancelled', 'recurringEventId': 'm80coonp168fml4hec4tq777cc', 'originalStartTime': {'dateTime': '2021-01-04T07:00:00-06:00', 'timeZone': 'America/Mexico_City'}}
```

As you can see both return the same json information and also a 410 error mentioning that the 'Resource has been deleted' which is not true since I'm still able to view, edit and delete it manually from my google calendars on the web browser.

Again any help would be amazing!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over instances of the recurring event but always trying to delete the recurring event and not its instance. See this line:

```
googleServices['Calendar'].events().delete(calendarId=calendar['id'], eventId=instance['recurringEventId']).execute()
```

`instance['recurringEventId']` is the same for each instance. You should be using `instance['id']`

Comment: Hello, I've tried this solution and it does delete most of the events however, when I see my actual calendar app on the browser it's very clear that it did not delete all of the events. When I run the code again, It doesn't get any events for the calendar even though they still have events in them... Any idea of what's happening here? I'm pretty lost with why it's behaving that way

Comment: The only way I've been able to consistently delete all events is using a google script that basically does the same... However for our implementation we can only use python and the google api which makes continuing to delete the events using google script non efective.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help this was indeed the solutions I had been struggling on for this project to work flawlessly :)